# WSO2 Api Manager RestApiAdmin wsdl usage

Tags: wsdl, wso2-api-manager, wso2, api-manager

in wso2 api manager what is the usage of this wsdl:
RestApiAdmin

https://[apim-host]:[apim-port]/services/RestApiAdmin?wsdl

this is add api but dont show in publisher or store or carbon

what is this usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the admin service that is used to deploy APIs to the gateway. When you create an API in the API publisher, the API publisher calls this API in the gateway to deploy that API in the gateway.

Comment: These are internal APIs that are used for publisher to gateway communication. If you want to use an API to create APIs, then you can use REST APIs that are exposed in the product. Plz refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/product-apis/publisher-apis/publisher-v1/publisher-v1/

Comment: please answer this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64735080/monetization-in-wso2-api-manager-version-2-6-0