# Monetization in wso2 api manager version 2.6.0

Tags: wso2, ibm-api-management

How can use monetization in wso2 api manager version 2.6.0?
it have label for free or paid for example:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+API+Monetization+Category+Labels

But I dont want label.
I want calculate money for per api and user see api  price.
for example user used api and per request I can calculate and report monetization.

Comment: Plz check this - http://www.rukspot.com/blog/monetization_and_sample_with_wso2_api_manager_260